# Everytime I opened my mac terminal it showing that

Tags: terminal, homebrew, zsh, nvm

Last login: Sun Jan 29 10:12:00 on ttys000

/Users/aman/.zshrc:.:4: not enough arguments

/Users/aman/.zshrc:5: permission denied: /opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh

/Users/aman/.zshrc:.:6: not enough arguments

/Users/aman/.zshrc:7: permission denied: /opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm

/Users/aman/.zshrc:8: command not found: bash_completion

Can you please eplain why is it showing ? I am using Macbook air M1 ventura. How to solve it. Every time I opened terminal it is showing like that. It is very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you followed the instruction in `brew info nvm` and copied the script to `~/.zshrc`

Delete the script and replace it by

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
. $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have some config in your .zshrc file that might not have everythin it needs to work.

the .zshrc file seems like its trying to run some setup related to nvm or Node Version Manager. that might be because zsrch config was copied from another machine, or because it was edited to include this setup by an installation script.

Check if you have node version manager installed or remove it from your .zshrc file.

you can install nvm with `brew install nvm`